# Change metadata and artifact Repository names with p2 and Ant builder from build.xml file

Tags: eclipse, p2, pde, antbuilder

I want to change the name of my resulting repositories when running a Ant build for a deplayable feature from:
"repository name='file://buildRepo - artifacts' t.." 
to a more friendly one. i have tried using

```
...
<property name="p2.metadata.repo"       value="file:${basedir}/buildRepo"/>
<property name="p2.metadata.repo.name"       value="Friendly Name"/>
    <property name="p2.artifact.repo"       value="file:${basedir}/buildRepo"/>
    <property name="p2.artifact.repo.name"       value="Friendly Name"/>
..
<eclipse.gatherFeature 
       metadataRepository="${p2.metadata.repo}"
       metadataRepositoryName="${p2.metadata.repo.name}"
       artifactRepository="${p2.artifact.repo}"
       artifactRepositoryName="${p2.artifact.repo.name}"
       buildResultFolder="${feature.temp.folder}"
       baseDirectory="${basedir}"
    />
...
```

The p2.gathering is not used so that these cand apply (as documented in the Eclipse wiki).
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the generation of your repo you can use the p2.mirror ant task to accomplish this. A detailed description of the task can be found here. [Eclipse p2 mirror help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_repositorytasks.htm?resultof=%22%70%32%2e%6d%69%72%72%6f%72%22%20).

```
<p2.mirror source="${p2.artifact.repo}">
<destination location="file:///${p2.artifact.repo}_beautifulName" name="p2.repo.name"  />
```

or separte mirror tasks for metadata and artifact if you need them.

Comment: Thanks. The repository name is changed during the mirroring process. It is a good workaround. :)